# Flutter GetX: Refreshing Data on the Same Page with Get.offNamed() and Updating URL

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx, flutter-navigation

I'm developing a Flutter web application using the GetX package for state management and navigation. I have a page where users can select filters from a bottom sheet, and based on these filters, a list of posts is fetched and displayed on the page.

The problem I'm facing is that when the user selects filters and presses the "Load posts" button, I want the page to refresh and display the new posts based on the selected filters. However, nothing happens when the button is pressed.

Additionally, I want the URL in the address bar to update based on the selected filters. For example, if the user selects "Funny" as the category, the URL should update to `/posts?category=Funny`. This way, if a user directly goes to `/posts?category=Funny`, they would see posts in the "Funny" category.

Here's the code for the "Load Posts" button:

```dart
ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: () {
    Get.offNamed(
      '/posts',
      arguments: {
        'category': _filterController.selectedCategory.value,
        'orderBy': _filterController.orderBy.value,
        'isDescending': _filterController.isDescending.value,
      },
    );
  },
  child: const Text('Load Posts'),
),
```

In this code, I'm using `Get.offNamed()` to navigate to the current route ('/Posts') with new arguments. My expectation is that this would force a rebuild of the page with the new arguments. However, this is not happening.

I also tried using `Get.toNamed()` instead of `Get.offNamed()`, but this didn't work either.

How can I refresh the data on the same page in Flutter using GetX when new filters are selected and update the URL in the address bar accordingly?

Comment: Why use Get.toNamed or Get.offNamed? As you are updating or refreshing the data on the same controller, you can use update() if you are using GetBuilder or obx will refresh the record once it receives from the API call. I don't think you need to navigate to a new screen to update the UI. Make sure to use the same controller.

Comment: I don't have any issue getting the fresh data, right now I'm using posts controller.getposts() and it works very well. What I want is to also update the address bar to latest parameters e.g. if I'm on /posts after refreshing the data with new filters it should update like this /posts?category=Funny

Comment: i am not getting back stack any update on this ?